# ES6, Lodash sortBy 2 level array of objects

Tags: javascript, sorting, ecmascript-6, lodash

Can't figure out how to sort this kind of structure:

```
[
  0: { text: 'Lorem', 'children': [ 0: { text: 'Ipsum of Lorem' } ... ] }
  ...
]
```

I can only sort by the first level like this: `_.sortBy(myArray,'text')`

I need something like `_.sortBy(myArray, ['text','children.text'])` this obviously doesn't work.

I need to sort by children.text of each item.

Comment: Do you want to sort the children array of each object?

Comment: Or do you want to sort the array myArray based on the first index of the array children?

Comment: First I want to sort first level, I already done this like this: _.sortBy(myArray,'text') but additionally, I need to sort children of each first level item.

Comment: So, of the first level has two items with the same text, do the children then affect how that top level is sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should loop over the children array.

```js
const myArray = [{ text: 'ZLorem', 'children': [{ text: 'Ipsum2' }, { text: 'Apsum2' }] },{ text: 'Lorem', 'children': [{ text: 'Ipsum1' }, { text: 'Zpsum1' }] }],
      result = _.sortBy(myArray, 'text');
      
result.forEach(o => {
  if (o.children) 
    o.children = _.sortBy(o.children, 'text');
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to sort by the 1st item of the `children` array, you can use `'children[0].text'`:

```js
const myArray = [
  { text: 'Lorem', 'children': [{ text: 'Ipsum2' }] },
  { text: 'Lorem', 'children': [{ text: 'Ipsum1' }] }
]

const result = _.sortBy(myArray, ['text','children[0].text'])

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

If you need to sort the children, and then use the 1st item, you can generate a function with `_.flow()`. The function starts by mapping each object, and sorting it's `children`, and then sorts the entire array:

```js
const { flow, partialRight: pr, map, sortBy } = _

const fn = flow(
  pr(map, o => ({ ...o, children: sortBy(o.children, 'text') })),
  pr(sortBy, ['text','children[0].text'])
)

const myArray = [
  { text: 'Lorem', 'children': [{ text: 'Ipsum2' }, { text: 'Ipsum4' }] },
  { text: 'Lorem', 'children': [{ text: 'Ipsum3' }, { text: 'Ipsum1' }] }
]

const result = fn(myArray)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

And the same idea but terser with lodash/fp:

```js
const { flow, map, sortBy } = _

const fn = flow(
  map(o => ({ ...o, children: sortBy('text', o.children) })),
  sortBy(['text','children[0].text'])
)

const myArray = [
  { text: 'Lorem', 'children': [{ text: 'Ipsum2' }, { text: 'Ipsum4' }] },
  { text: 'Lorem', 'children': [{ text: 'Ipsum3' }, { text: 'Ipsum1' }] }
]

const result = fn(myArray)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop to trace the children and sort the children array.

```
_.sortBy(myArray, 'text');
for(let parent of myArray) {
    _.sortBy(parent.children, 'text');
}
```

This code should do like you want or you can create it as function

```
function sortParentAndChildren(myArray, key) {
    _.sortBy(myArray, key);
    for (let parent of myArray) {
        _.sortBy(parent.children, key);
    }
}

sortParentAndChildren(myArray, "text");
```